# Associating rows from uploaded CSV files with a User in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm following the first half of http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel to upload CSV files and create new "samples" in my rails app.

I'm trying to create a mysamples page that renders only the current user's samples. So far if I add a sample one at a time through a form it will show up on this page.

But when I upload the CSV the new samples aren't getting associated with the user.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Sample_Controller.rb

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_sample, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 after_action :verify_authorized

respond_to :html
def home
  @samples = Sample.all
  authorize @samples 
end

def admin_only
end

def index
  @q = Sample.search(params[:q])
  @samples = @q.result(distinct: true).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page    => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )
  respond_with(@samples)
  authorize @samples
end

def mysample
  @samples = Sample.all
  authorize @samples
end

def import
  @samples = Sample.all
  if params[:file].present?
  Sample.import(params[:file], params[:user_id])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Samples Imported"
  else
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You need to choose a file first!"
  end
  authorize @samples
end

def show
  respond_with(@sample)
end

def new
  @sample = Sample.new
  respond_with(@sample)
  authorize @sample
end

def edit
end

def create
  params[:sample][:user_id] = current_user.id
  @sample = Sample.new(sample_params)
  authorize @sample
  if @sample.save
    redirect_to @sample, notice: 'Sample was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
 end
end

def update
  if @sample.update(sample_params)
  redirect_to @sample, notice: 'Sample was successfully updated.'
else
  render action: 'edit'
end
```

end

```
def destroy
  @sample.destroy
  authorize @sample
  respond_with(@sample)
end

private
  def set_sample
    @sample = Sample.find(params[:id])
    authorize @sample
  end

  def sample_params
    params.require(:sample).permit(:line, :season, :style, :color, :date_out, :to_who, :date_in, :location,:user_id)
  end
```

end

Sample.rb model

class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Sample.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

mysample.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

<% @samples.each do |sample| %>
    <% if sample.user == current_user %>
          <div class="row sample"> 

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <strong>Line</strong>
              <%= sample.line %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <strong>Season</strong>
              <%= sample.season %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>Style</strong>
              <%= sample.style %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>Color</strong>
              <%= sample.color%>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>Date Out</strong>
              <%= sample.date_out %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>To Who</strong>
              <%= sample.to_who %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>Date In</strong>
              <%= sample.date_in %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <strong>Location</strong>
              <%= sample.location %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 bottom">
             <%= link_to 'Check In | Out', edit_sample_path(sample), class: "btn btn-md btn-default"  %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>


</div>
```

**EDIT** I used byebug to step through the model and haven't gotten any errors. But the last time I did it, I quit byebug, shut down the server, the restarted it and hit refresh on this url http://localhost:3000/samples/import

This led to an error I hadn't seen. 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your form that posts to import as well please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing in the user id so merge the user_id onto your hash:

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Sample.import(params[:file], current_user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

You could find the user and do it through an association to ensure the user exists - how you want to deal with it not existing I leave to you.  Using find_by so it doesn't throw an active record not found error, if you want that then just use find instead.

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        user.samples.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried both versions. The first option loads the file but it's still not getting associated. The second option gets this error. undefined method `find_by' for nil:NilClass...

Comment: Second one I should have had a capital, sorry.  You are passing `params[:user_id]` to the controller right? and you have a `user_id` field on the  `Sample` model

Comment: ok adding the capital U made it upload but it's still not associating. I edited the post to include my entire sample controller.

Comment: UPDATE: the last sample stored in my db sample.last shows up as the one I last created in the new sample form not the upload. so it makes me think that although uploaded csv samples show up in the index, they aren't getting stored with an id or user id.. Thoughts?

Comment: I assume you're not posting it via the form.

Comment: That is correct. I've got a separate upload button and field on the home page.

Comment: So I added an edit above. I got a new error fully explained above. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok so in your import method you need something like this:
`Sample.import(params[:file], current_user.id)`.  Your other error is due to your routing.

Comment: That did the trick!! thanks, I updated the answer to reflect your last comment. Thanks so much for your help.